What are changes on android 14 that affects ANR on flutter apps on bacground mode?
I am getting ANR reports on crashlytics when the app is in background but it only appears on the Android version >=14. Sadly I cannot reproduce it on the emulator and I do not have an Android 14 device.
It doesn't mention particularly any native method that I can pinpoint to any features that my app uses
Major features my app uses that might have something to do with  the Background ANR are:

location tracking
local and push notification
firebase firestore

Below is the textual version of the bug report
 main (native):tid=1 systid=12610 
#00 pc 0xc7d28 libc.so (__epoll_pwait + 8) (BuildId: 1d36f8ae6e0af6158793abea7d4f4f2b)
#01 pc 0xfc28 libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce + 184) (BuildId: c07f08c7e5a964a8f8c6bc5c820fb795)
#02 pc 0x18c53c libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce + 44) (BuildId: e0fc1ccfe043ab286e745f48696bc0d8)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:349)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:189)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8592)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:878)

The list of dependency I am using
dependencies:
  address: ^0.1.0+2
  flutter:
      sdk: flutter
  battery_plus: ^5.0.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  confetti: ^0.7.0
  dartx: ^1.2.0
  flutter_osm_plugin: ^1.3.0
  dropdown_search: ^5.0.6
  email_validator: ^2.1.16
  easy_localization: ^3.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.9.0
  firebase_analytics: ^10.2.1
  flutter_card_swiper: ^6.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.6
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.0.12
  firebase_core: ^2.24.2
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.12
  firebase_database: ^10.0.10
  firebase_messaging: ^14.2.2
  firebase_performance: ^0.9.2+7
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.11
  flutter_picker_plus: ^1.2.0
  fl_chart: ^0.68.0
  flutter_background_geolocation: ^4.15.5
  duration_picker: 
    path: packages/duration_picker
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  flutter_image_compress: ^2.1.0
  flutter_stripe: ^9.6.0
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3
  flutter_polyline_points: ^2.0.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.2.2
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.7
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.7.0
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.9
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  flutter_chat_types: ^3.6.2
  logging: ^1.2.0
  #geolocator: ^8.2.1
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  google_fonts: ^4.0.4
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.5.0
  google_maps_place_picker_mb: ^3.1.2
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.6
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  http: ^1.2.0
  image_picker: ^1.0.4
  location: ^5.0.0
  lottie: ^2.3.2
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.3
  permission_handler: ^11.0.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.17
  share_plus: ^7.2.1
  rxdart: ^0.27.7
  sign_in_with_apple: ^6.1.2
  # tflite_flutter: ^0.9.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.18
  diacritic: ^0.1.4
  device_info_plus: ^9.0.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.5
  flash: ^3.0.5+2
  uuid: ^4.3.3
  webview_flutter: ^4.4.2
  flutter_date_pickers: ^0.4.3
  meta: ^1.8.0
  # date_time_picker: ^2.1.0
  # flutter_datetime_picker:
  #     git:
  #         url: https://github.com/Realank/flutter_datetime_picker.git
  #         ref: master
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  showcaseview: ^3.0.0
  package_info_plus: ^5.0.1
  version: ^3.0.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  flutter_custom_clippers: ^2.0.0
  barcode_widget: ^2.0.4
  flutter_countdown_timer: ^4.1.0
  flutter_widget_from_html_core: ^0.14.9
  tutorial_coach_mark: ^1.2.11
  flutter_typeahead: ^5.2.0
  community_charts_flutter: 1.0.1
  stacked: ^3.4.0
  # day_picker: ^2.2.0
  time_range: ^1.1.0
  flutter_chat_ui: ^1.6.6
  firebase_remote_config: ^4.2.6
  collection: ^1.15.0-nullsafety.4
  geolocator: 10.1.1
  app_settings: ^5.1.1
  firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.7.5+7
  firebase_app_installations: ^0.2.5+7
  pointer_interceptor: ^0.10.1+2
  mapbox_search: any
  polyline_codec: ^0.1.6

dependency_overrides:
  package_info_plus: ^4.1.0
  google_api_headers: ^3.2.1
  web: ^1.0.0
  flutter_osm_web: ^1.3.0
  google_maps_flutter_platform_interface: ^2.9.2
  # firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.8.0
  #test_api: 0.4.18
  # stripe_android: "9.5.0+1"
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^2.1.2
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  lint: ^2.0.20
  dependency_validator: ^3.2.2

Any clue what might be causing it?
some images from crashlytics




Unfortunately that trace you gave us is the wrong thread-  that thread is polling on the message queue, so it isn't in an ANR state.  Do you have a bigger stack trace?

Also, do you use JobScheduler (or does Flutter?).  Because one change in 14 was to make jobs in JobScheduler that take too long ANR.

thats all the trace I got from firebase crashlytics.
I do not use jobschedular directly. I think firestore and flutter_background_golocation may be using it
